# Update source code in aws with Circleci when the github branch is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, circleci

I would like to write a command in the circleci such that the source code in the aws is updated, when the code in github branch is updated. I am currently using amazon ec2 instance.

PS: I am new to circleci. I have connected ssh key to ec2 instance through fingerprints. Currently we are trying to convert the gitlab.ci to circle ci.  In the gitlab.ci they have used docker to pull and run the github repository on aws ec2 instance. However, we want to store and update the source code in the aws ec2 instance. I have checked the documentation of [aws integration with circleci](https://circleci.com/integrations/aws/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=sem&utm_campaign=sem-google-partner--emea-en-aws-maxConv-auth-nb&utm_term=g_b-%2Baws%20%2Bcircle_c__pipeline_20200730&utm_content=sem-google-partner--emea-en-aws-maxConv-auth-nb_keyword-text_eta-awsCircleci_mixed-&gclid=CjwKCAjwzaSLBhBJEiwAJSRokvDcpF62sJQ362lW2FhaVK6pNJgb2cxwRMODIWtqPTStHhunDKXJZRoCqWwQAvD_BwE) and also using [orbs to connect to aws ec2](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecs). However these documentation have templates to connect aws instances with orbs and run tasks, but not store files.

Comment: What have you tried? Any commands? Any research done at all?

Comment: I have updated the post, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used bash file to sync the aws files. And ran ssh command to run bash file in circleci.